# Use HTML to detect IE newer than 7 or other browser

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, compatibility

I want to use display `A` for IE great than 7 or other browsers, and display `B` for IE 7 and lower.

One way is

```
<!--[if !IE]>
A
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 8]>
A
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
B
<![endif]-->
```

But I don't want to write `A` twice in a page since `A` is very long and it seems unwise to duplicate it.

How can I achieve this by HTML only?

Comment: *sidenote:* if possible, please stop serving old IE browsers; ask them to upgrade instead.

Comment: @Raptor Of course I want to... But my client had me to achieve this.

Comment: With HTML *only*, it's inevitable to duplicate the codes. However, there are several JS libraries that detects browsers and display certain contents, such as Modernizr , yepnone.js , etc